# How to prioritize firebase web auth before loading my web page

Tags: firebase, authentication, web, firebase-authentication

I have a simple login layout. I want to stop loading or displaying it when the user is logged in the web page. Everything is ok but there seems to be a slight delay when verifying firebase auth that's why whenever I refresh my web page, the login layout still displays very briefly though. I want it to not be seen totally.

[Here is the video of my problem](https://youtu.be/W99J6FHE6vs)

As you can see, In the video the user is already logged in. But the username and password and button for login is still showing very briefly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't share any code, but I make the assumption that you use the [`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth?authuser=0#onauthstatechanged) observer. As explained in the doc, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users?authuser=0#the_user_lifecycle) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=0#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), the `Auth` object needs to initialize before the observer is triggered, therefore you cannot avoid the behaviour you experience.

You need to manage yourself the displaying as follows:

- Before the `Auth` object is fully initialized (i.e. the Auth object is in an intermediate state), show a welcome/default page with spinner
- If the user is already signed-in show the relevant page
- If the user is not signed-in show the login page

Something along the following (pseudo commented code) lines:

```
// Show the spinner
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    // Hide the spinner and show content
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    // Hide the spinner and show the login form
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is the format that I was using for verifying user authentication. Okay I'll try that method you gave. thanks.

Comment: I fixed it though without a spinner/loader. Rather, I initialized all the objects with display: none, So that the firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged will decide what objects to display first.